# Accessing first element of array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting below json from backend.

```
{ drug:
  {

    "id": "580f323ee4b06ffee69041a1",
    "direction": [
        {
            "direction": "test",
            "discarded": false
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I dont want direction as array. I want it as object so I wrote method drug_format to parse json

My ruby on rails code for parsing is as follows :

```
def drug_format drug
{
  id: drug[:id],
  direction: drug[:direction][0],
}
end
```

Now when I am trying to run my code I am getting following error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    app/controllers/drugs_controller.rb:280:in `drug_format'
    app/controllers/drugs_controller.rb:15:in `block in index'
    app/controllers/drugs_controller.rb:14:in `each'
    app/controllers/drugs_controller.rb:14:in `index'
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: How do you call `drug_format`?

Comment: drug_format(drug)

Comment: What is `drug` and what does `drug[:id]` or `drug[:direction]` return?

Comment: drug[:id] returns string and drug[:direction] returns array of object. I want to access first object of array.

Comment: If `drug` is a hash and `drug[:direction]` returns an array, then neither `drug[:id]` nor `drug[:direction][0]` would raise that error.

Comment: Sorry, if you pass provided Hash to method `drug_format` then you need to use it as `{ id: drug[:drug][:id], direction: drug[:drug][:direction][0]}` (maybe with string keys instead of symbols)

Comment: Your JSON is not correct. Take away this comma in `direction: drug[:direction][0],`, because there is no reason for it to be there. A comma says there will be another key after that element.

Answer (score 2):

the json keys are strings and not symbols, so you need something like:

```
def drug_format drug
  {
    id: drug['id'],
    direction: drug['direction'][0]
  }
end
```

or you can use [`with_indifferent_access`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-with_indifferent_access)

console output:

```
params = {
 'drug' => {
    "id" => "580f323ee4b06ffee69041a1",
    "direction" => [
        {
            "direction" => "test",
            "discarded" => false
        }
    ]
  }
}
=> {"drug"=>{"id"=>"580f323ee4b06ffee69041a1", "direction"=>[{"direction"=>"test", "discarded"=>false}]}}

params[:drug]
=> nil

params['drug']
=> {"id"=>"580f323ee4b06ffee69041a1", "direction"=>[{"direction"=>"test", "discarded"=>false}]}

def drug_format(drug)
  {
    id: drug['id'],
    direction: drug['direction'][0]
  }
end
=> :drug_format

drug_format(params[:drug])
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

drug_format(params['drug'])
=> {:id=>"580f323ee4b06ffee69041a1", :direction=>{"direction"=>"test", "discarded"=>false}}
```

Comment: it might an issue accessing the drug param... please note my edited answer

Comment: GEnerated JSON is not correct. Take away this comma in `direction: drug[:direction][0],`, because there is no reason for it to be there. A comma says there will be another key after that element.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida that doesn't matter in ruby

Comment: @EddeAlmeida just checked your profile, correct if I said something wrong.. You shoud have digged ruby a lot ;)

Comment: I just tell you that Ruby checks systax strictly and is unlikely to return a badly formatted object. But I haven't tested this and I'm assuming you did.

Comment: Yes I did and the `,` is handeled so `{a: 'abc', }` dosn't throw any errors

Comment: Nice to know that.

Comment: I've copied the method from OP :/ it doesn't throw erros, but no reason to have a `,`... I've edited it anyway ;)